# what does happen while recycling view in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, bitmap

I want to know the recycling concept of listview in android. Here i am using the listview with image and text on the every list item. The following are my doubts,

1.What does happen while recycling of list item in listview? Does the memory of object created(in getView()) is cleared?

2.While recycling the list item, why the view reference is not recycled and added to convertview? If its in convertview, what will happen to the bitmap which is loaded already in the listitem. Does listview keep referencing the bitmap or clear the memory of bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

> What does happen while recycling of list item in listview? Does the
>   memory of object created(in getView()) is cleared?

If you are using [`ViewHolder` pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder), then object will not be cleared from memory. Rather same `View` object(s) will be used for next data item.

> While recycling the list item, why the view reference is not recycled
>   and added to convertview? If its in convertview, what will happen to
>   the bitmap which is loaded already in the listitem. Does listview keep
>   referencing the bitmap or clear the memory of bitmap?

To reccle `View` reference, you would need to use `ViewHolder` pattern. Already loaded `Bitmap` will be there till you update/clear the `ImageView`.

Comment: View holder doesn't really have anything to do with view recycling. It's just a cache of `findViewById()` results for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.What does happen while recycling of list item in listview? Does the memory of object created(in getView()) is cleared?

A `View` you returned from `getView()` is passed in as as an argument to another call to `getView()` as the `convertView`.

Whether you return it back after reconfiguring for the row position, or return a new `View`, is up to you.

If you don't hold a reference to the `convertView` yourself and don't return it, then it becomes eligible for garbage collection since listview itself will only keep a reference to the view you returned from `getView()`.

> 2.While recycling the list item, why the view reference is not recycled and added to convertview?

I have no idea what you are asking here.

> If its in convertview, what will happen to the bitmap which is loaded already in the listitem. Does listview keep referencing the bitmap or clear the memory of bitmap?

Listview doesn't care about the internals of views.

Again, if you don't hold a reference to any views or bitmaps, eventually the garbage collector will take care of them.

Comment: hi laalto,if i reuse the convertview(It holds the bitmap reference), the heap memory will increase right?

Comment: If you don't leak memory (i.e. hold references unnecessarily), the memory will eventually get reclaimed by GC.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am going to develop the application like Facebook(The infinite list rows with images and text). Whether this is good practice to reuse the convertview reference?

Comment: Yes, reuse convertView when non-null instead of creating a new view.

Comment: thanks. Do i have to null the bitmap reference while recycle listening in listview to avoid heap size increasing?.